# Criar interface gráfica usando MigLayout

Tags: java, swing

Preciso criar esta interface gráfica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O último código que tentei foi este:
(mas as configurações não estão corretas)

```
frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap","[grow]","[grow][]"));
 panelInfo.setLayout(new MigLayout(""));
 panelInfo.add(new JLabel("tessssssstteeetsssssssss"), "grow, pushx, pushy, wrap");

 //panelMenu.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill","[] [] []"));
 panelMenu.setLayout(new MigLayout(""));
 panelMenu.add(anterior,"align center");
 panelMenu.add(proximo,"align center");
 panelMenu.add(backMenu,"align right");

 frame.getContentPane().add(panelInfo);
 frame.getContentPane().add(panelMenu);
```

Comment: Você tem que usar o MigLayout? Para fixar componentes no rodapé sou muito mais usar o BorderLayout e colocá-los no South do panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu faria uma composição de Layouts, para fixar os componentes no rodapé usaria o BorderLayout e colocaria um `panel` na posição PAGE_END.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `panel` do PAGE_END também seria do tipo BorderLayout, para pode fixar o botão de Sair à direita (LINE_END), e teria outro `panel` para colocar os dois botões de navegação, esses na posição CENTER. Para os `panel`s dos botões, eu usaria MigLayout para deixá-los responsivos.

A estrutura ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado final ficaria o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class ComposicaoDeLayouts extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ComposicaoDeLayouts frame = new ComposicaoDeLayouts();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ComposicaoDeLayouts() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel pnlCenter = new JPanel();
        pnlCenter.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.add(pnlCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(pnlSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pnlSouth.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel pnlBotoesNavegacao = new JPanel();
        pnlSouth.add(pnlBotoesNavegacao, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnlBotoesNavegacao.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[1,grow 2][100px][100px][1,grow 1]", "[40px]"));

        JButton btnAnterior = new JButton("<< Anterior");
        pnlBotoesNavegacao.add(btnAnterior, "cell 1 0,grow");

        JButton btnProximo = new JButton("Proximo >>");
        pnlBotoesNavegacao.add(btnProximo, "cell 2 0,grow");

        JPanel pnlBotaoSair = new JPanel();
        pnlSouth.add(pnlBotaoSair, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pnlBotaoSair.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[100px]", "[40px]"));

        JButton btnSair = new JButton("Sair");
        pnlBotaoSair.add(btnSair, "cell 0 0,grow");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Math não tinha pensado na composição de Layouts, ainda não testei mas era isto que queria :) quanto ao uso do `MigLayout` era mais para aprender a usa-lo...

Comment: @jsantos1991 o MigLayout é bem flexível e realmente vale a pena aprendê-lo, mas eu não costumo fazer nada na mão, eu uso o plugin WindowBuilder no Eclipse para criar as telas. E apesar de ele ser um dos mais completos dos Layout Managers, quase sempre é necessário fazer uma composição de Layout para se obter o resultado desejado.